# Why incremental load inserts duplicate records to HANA?

Tags: hana

My query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TARGET TABLE
 (
      id
     ,order_no
     ,event_ts
     ,rcrd_cre_ts
 )
 SELECT
       src.id
      ,src.order_no
      ,src.event_ts
      ,UTCTOLOCAL(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'PST') 
  FROM    
  (
    SELECT
         CAST(id AS VARCHAR(40)) AS id
        ,event_ts
        ,CAST(order_no AS VARCHAR(20)) AS order_no
    FROM
     STAGE TABLE
    WHERE order_no <> ''
      AND order_no IS NOT NULL
   ) src
   LEFT JOIN TARGET TABLE
     ON (src.id = tgt.id AND src.order_no = tgt.order_no AND src.event_ts = tgt.event_ts )
   AND tgt.order_no IS NULL
 ;
```

I'm already casting `event_ts` as TIMESTAMP in the stage table itself. Let's say I already have a record 1 like this in the target table, if I run the same job again, it is inserting a duplicate record into the target table with the below `id`, `order` and `event_ts` key combination. My assumption is something got wrong around `event_ts`. though it's showing `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, it is storing something else. Can someone help where am I going wrong?

```
EX45ERC657 2021-07-02 13:31:02  25 2021-07-02 14:46:11
EX45ERC657 2021-07-02 13:31:02  25 2021-07-02 14:52:11
```

`event_ts` from source is coming as example:

```
2021-07-02T13:31:02.209Z
```

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` already provides the local timezone (local = the server time zone) - so applying `UTCTOLOCAL` is not correct here. `CURRENT_UTCTIMESTAMP` may be applicable here, instead,  if the target timezone is meant to always be `PST`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue. Instead of

```
LEFT JOIN TARGET TABLE
     ON (src.id = tgt.id AND src.order_no = tgt.order_no AND src.event_ts = tgt.event_ts )
   AND tgt.order_no IS NULL
```

it has to be

```
LEFT JOIN TARGET TABLE
     ON (src.id = tgt.id AND src.order_no = tgt.order_no AND src.event_ts = tgt.event_ts )
   where tgt.order_no IS NULL

Sorry, but it seem to be working.
```

Comment: The important bit to note here is the logical sequence of when filters are applied. Join conditions (`ON` clause) are processed before the `WHERE` clause is applied. WIth an `IS NULL` condition on the outer table of your join (`TARGET`) only records with **no match** are selected - which is consistent with the requirement of loading only records that are not yet present.